# No Google navigation in Android webview

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I launched Google map in a webview but the map doesn't have a link to navigation. I only get written directions like the old Google navigation in desktop. I have the latest Google map app installed in the phone and I would like to use that from my app or similar capability Google map from the browser. If my question is not clear please ask and I will clarify. Thanks.[image]

```
public class Direction_Map_Fragment extends FragmentActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.direction_map_layout);
        String dr = getIntent().getExtras().get("d").toString();
        String ps = getIntent().getExtras().get("p").toString();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
                viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
                return false;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+dr + "&daddr="+ps);

    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loading the URL in a `WebView` you could launch an `Intent` which should prompt the user to load in a browser or Google maps.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

The Google Maps for Android application also provides several [`Intent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=en)s. One of which will start navigation:

```
google.navigation:q=a+street+address
google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude
```

**Example:**

> The below Intent will request turn-by-turn navigation to Taronga Zoo, in Sydney Australia:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Last but not least you could use the [Google Maps Android API](https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html) in your application (not sure if it provides navigation).

> Allow your users to explore the world with rich maps provided by Google. Identify locations with custom markers, augment the map data with image overlays, embed one or more maps as fragments, and much more.
>
> The [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) allows you to include maps and customized mapping information in your app.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But that would not allow me to cancel the navigation based on my other application's request. I would like to be able to cancel the navigation based on my application's needs. I tried to call finish() but that would simply hang the app and freeze the screen. I am trying to stay within my app so I have more freedom. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you simply want to give the user a choice to launch navigation you could add a button over top of the WebView to launch the intent as in my example. If however you want to be able to start/stop navigation in your application you might need to check out the Google Maps API (not sure if it provides navigation as I haven't used it) https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html

Comment: I have another android app which the user mentioned above is going to. If that user wants to cancel the trip, I would like to cancel the navigation and show a little toast message or something in the screen and redirect to the app. I tried to pass an intent to redirect from google navigation to my app but I don't know how.

Comment: @The_Martian in addition to my above comment it looks like Google Maps for Android application also exposes several Intents for controlling functionality https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=en I see one to start navigation but nothing to stop it (which makes sense from a "security" side actually)